# Need help finding xpath of input field beside label

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a dom structure like this

```
<tr class="">
<td class="labelCol requiredInput">
    <label for="name_lastacc2" class="">
        <span class="requiredMark">*</span>
    Last Name</label>
</td>
<td class="dataCol col02">
    <div class="requiredInput">
        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
        <input id="name_lastacc2" maxlength="80" name="name_lastacc2" size="20" tabindex="3" type="text"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="labelCol">
        <label for="00NG0000008Rybp">Business Ext.</label>
    </td>
    <td class="dataCol">
        <input id="00NG0000008Rybp" maxlength="10" name="00NG0000008Rybp" size="20" tabindex="22" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to find the input box next to its label.

Eg:

Last Name: ________________

I have tried using xpath queries like

```
//label[contains(text(),'Last Name']/../following-sibling::*/div/input[@type='text']
```

but i get an [INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION] error. Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your path expression is missing the closing bracket of `contains()`.

```
//label[contains(text(),'Last Name')]/../following-sibling::*/div/input[@type='text']
```

But that said, I do not think your path expression is correct now. Your expression will match *any* following sibling of the parent of `label[contains(text(),'Last Name')]`. What you want it to find is the `input` element that immediately follows.

The only reason your original expression only finds one `input` element is that the second one is nested inside one more `div`. But I do not think you should rely on that.

Instead, try:

```
//label[contains(.,'Last Name')]/following::input[1]
```

Then, the result is

```
<input id="name_lastacc2" maxlength="80" name="name_lastacc2" size="20" tabindex="3" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Ahh crap! I have been sitting over this for an hour now. How stupid of me. Thanks !

Comment: @user2148105 You are welcome. Please also have a look at my edit.

Comment: but following wud take everything that comes after the td right ? I am trying to restrict my scope within the next td

Comment: @user2148105 No, it only considers what comes after until the first `input` element is found. Which is exactly what you want I think. By the way, why do you not look for a `label` and an `input` element where the attributes `for` and `id` match?

Comment: I followed ur suggestion for a select element having the same structure. I tried selenium to select that option    find(:xpath,"//label[contains(text(),'#{label}')]/../following::select[1]/option[contains(text(),'#{option}')]").click  But I am getting the error Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '//label[contains(text(),'Record Type of new record')]/../following::select[1]/option[contains(text(),'1. Individual')]' is not a valid selector. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user2148105 I am not familiar with Selenium, only with XPath. But if you have a new question, please also open a new question post for it.